# Crm? Is it This name?

Tags: email, server, crm

I'm looking for a solution that integrates with the mail. The client writes an e-mail, the system gives the case number, then when we write, the thread is preserved.  I'd also like the unclosed threads to be displayed as this to...if it's Crm...?if you know a free system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call this a 'ticketing system', but the generic term is rather '**help desk software**'. [osTicket](https://osticket.com/) is an open-source example of this kind of systems. They are part of a bigger family: the CRM softwares.

Best regards